# Check which reaction a user picked [Discord.py]

Tags: discord.py

This should be fairly simple and I've been trying what I've googled but no luck. All I want to do is send a message regarding which emoji had more reactions. But nothing is being sent out.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'aoe2' in message.content and message.channel.id == 1048127088688889866:

        BlueEmbed = discord.Embed(title='AOE Lobby',
                                  description='**Lobby Link:** ' + '<' +
                                  str(message.content) + '>',
                                  colour=discord.Colour.blue())

   
        

        message = await message.channel.send(embed=BlueEmbed)
        await message.add_reaction('❤️')
        await message.add_reaction('')
        msg = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
        highest_reaction = ""
        highest_reaction_number = 0
        for reaction in msg.reactions:
            if reaction.count - 1 > highest_reaction_number:
                highest_reaction = reaction.emoji
                highest_reaction_count = reaction.count - 1
                await message.channel.send(f"{highest_reaction} wins with {highest_reaction_count} votes!")
```

the issue seems to be the program not waiting to check for votes, but rather executing the code instantly. Ignoring future reactions added. Not sure on a work around at this time. Seems I may need some sort of delay before running the if statement.

Comment: You are immediately counting reactions as soon as the message is sent. There will be no time for anyone to react.

Answer (score 0):

Use `asyncio.sleep()`

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if 'aoe2' in message.content and message.channel.id == 1048127088688889866:

    BlueEmbed = discord.Embed(title='AOE Lobby',
                              description='**Lobby Link:** ' + '<' +
                              str(message.content) + '>',
                              colour=discord.Colour.blue())


    

    message = await message.channel.send(embed=BlueEmbed)
    await message.add_reaction('❤️')
    await message.add_reaction('')
    await asyncio.sleep(5) #however long u want in seconds
    msg = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
    highest_reaction = ""
    highest_reaction_number = 0
    for reaction in msg.reactions:
        if reaction.count - 1 > highest_reaction_number:
            highest_reaction = reaction.emoji
            highest_reaction_count = reaction.count - 1
            await message.channel.send(f"{highest_reaction} wins with {highest_reaction_count} votes!")
```

or you can have another phrase trigger it

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  global messageid
  if 'aoe2' in message.content and message.channel.id == 1048127088688889866:

    BlueEmbed = discord.Embed(title='AOE Lobby',
                              description='**Lobby Link:** ' + '<' +
                              str(message.content) + '>',
                              colour=discord.Colour.blue())


    

    message = await message.channel.send(embed=BlueEmbed)
    await message.add_reaction('❤️')
    await message.add_reaction('')
    messageid = message.id
    
  if "trigger" in message.content and message.channel.id == 1048127088688889866::
    msg = await message.channel.fetch_message(messageid)
    highest_reaction = ""
    highest_reaction_number = 0
    for reaction in msg.reactions:
        if reaction.count - 1 > highest_reaction_number:
            highest_reaction = reaction.emoji
            highest_reaction_count = reaction.count - 1
            await message.channel.send(f"{highest_reaction} wins with {highest_reaction_count} votes!")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this worked. A slight adjustment, is there a way to do this with custom emojis?

here is my custom emoji:  

``` relic = '<:relic:1044382685591765052>' ``` 

and I added it to the embed with 

``` await message.add_reaction(relic) ```

but this if statement doesn't work

```if highest_reaction == relic:
              await message.channel.send('Relic')```

Comment: @JoshFsune There is a class in discord.py called `discord.Emoji`. It has many attributes such as `name`, `id` and `guild`, which you might find useful. For more info: [API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Emoji)